# How do I report a WP8 bug?

Tags: 8.0

Is it even possible? I mean I searched internet and my phone like for an hour and haven't found such thing as bug report for Microsoft.

Comment: Have you tried the [Microsoft Answers forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8?tab=Threads)?

Comment: What is the bug, can you share with us?

Comment: @NeilTurner Well, I just found there that there is thing like Suggestion Box (haven't heard of it till now), should I use it? (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpemail/how-to-file-bug-reports-with-microsoft/e573bc4a-5762-42d1-b356-273352a46ee2)

Comment: @DDC It is a pretty simple thing, I have changed a song from the lock screen, and when phone screen was just about to get dark, I've got a message. The thing is, the screen still went black so I could not read from whom I gotthe message in the (app update thingy in the top). It is just a bit odd, doesn't really break the phone or something.

Comment: Yes, there's no harm in reporting bugs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Reporting a bug through the phone itself

There is no built in module in the phone that allows you to reports bugs per se. You do have an option of allowing Microsoft (and Nokia if you have a Nokia handset) to gather usage details, etc. automatically.

#### Reporting a bug on the web

The best way to do this would be through the [Microsoft Community Forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/newthread?threadtype=Questions). Here, you can either open a new question or discussion pertaining specifically to Windows Phone.

#### Are you sure it is a bug?

Consider this:

- It could be behavior that has to do with settings that are perhaps not very intuitive. In such cases, you are almost better off posting on Windows Phone SE (this site).
- It could be a missing feature. In such cases, you are better off opening a feature request on the [Windows Phone User Voice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com) site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add you suggestions (bug reports) at http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/